# export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, ethers.js, usedapp

I trying to build a web app that can interact with blockchain, I'm using brownie as solidity framework and reactjs. I installed [useDapp](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/) to connect with my wallet. but in the first simple usage i got this error:

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/abi/multicall/constants.js 3:29-44

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/abi/multicall2/constants.js 3:29-44

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/constants/abi/index.js 7:18-33

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/helpers/address.js 9:29-45

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)

here is my App.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { DAppProvider, ChainId } from "@usedapp/core";


function App() {
  return (
    <DAppProvider config={{ supportedChains: [ChainId.Goerli] }}>
      <div>
        Hello!
      </div>
    </DAppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

please any suggestions to fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

Before:

```js
ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
```

After:

```js
ethers.formatEther(balance);
```

Answer (score 3):

finally, I figured out the problem
I removed the package 'ethers' and then I installed the version 5.6.9 manually with the following cmds:

```
$ yarn remove ethers
$ yarn add ethers@5.6.9
```

it worked fine for me

Comment: It works! Note that with `ethers@5.6.9` the compatible version is `@usedapp/core@1.2.1` (Currently the latest version is 1.2.7).

Answer (score 1):

ethers.js is moved from v5 to v6. So many things from v5 are no longer supported in v6 including utils. https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/

Your problem has two solutions:

1. Downgrade the ethers.js version to "5.7.2". If using npm run this command

```js
npm i ethers@5.7.2
```

2. If choose to use v6 then use like this:

```js
ethers.formatEthers(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats it.. latest solution to watch the migration doc for ethers v6 works. Downgrading v5 caused other problems to me.

So this worked for me:

- Fix follow migration to v6 guidelines on docs.ethers.org
  https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-utils

- use latest version, "ethers": "^6.6.4",
- change file extention .js --> .mjs
  (A file with .mjs extension is a JavaScript source code file that is used as an ECMA Module (ECMAScript Module) in Node.js applications.)
  https://docs.fileformat.com/web/mjs/
- change scripts

// imports
old:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { keccak256, toUtf8Bytes } from "ethers/lib/utils.js";
```

new:

```
import { ethers, keccak256, toUtf8Bytes  } from "ethers";
```

// getProvider
old:

```
function gp() {return new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(endpoint);
}
```

new:

```
function gp() {return new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(endpoint);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using ethers v6

Try:

```
ethers.formatEther(value);
```

Documentation here:
[ethers v6 #formatEther](https://docs.ethers.org/v6-beta/api/utils/#parseEther)